# how to do dojo internationalization

Tags: dojo, internationalization

1) I have webcontent/bpl/nls directory 
2) resource.js -.

```
define({  root: 
    ({
      software: " Software" 
    }),
    "fr": true,
    "fr-ca" : true,
    "en-us": true
});
```

I have this file inside webcontent/bpl/nls directory
3) 
In index.jsp, i am using like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        var dojoConfig = {
                async: true,
                parseOnLoad: true,
                locale: 'en-us',
                baseUrl: "/",
                tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
             };

        require(["dojo/i18n", "dojo/i18n!bpl/nls/resource"],function(
                    i18n, resource
            ){ alert(resource.software);}
                );          
</script>
```

BUT I am getting Undefined in alert box. What is the error ? what is right procedure ? I am using dojo 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the actual dictionary file for your locale. I.o.w, you would need a `webcontent/bpl/nls/en-us` folder with `resource.js` in it, having the following:

```
define({
    software: " Software" 
});
```

And similar ones for `fr` and `fr-ca` locales (since you declared them in your root dictionary).

See [dojo docs on i18n](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/i18n.html#usage) for more details.

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry Alamikh, the issue is, dojo is trying to search the resource.js from dojo's directory /dojo/1.8/bpl/nls/en-us

Comment: But i want to load from separate path Webcontent/bpl/nls Kindly help.I have a urgent delivery..

Comment: HEEELLLOO HELP NEEDED

Comment: Assuming you specified mapping to 'webcontent', I would say it's probably because your i18n path misses that prefix. I.o.w. it should be `dojo/i18n!webcontent/bpl/nls/en-us` instead of `dojo/i18n!bpl/nls/en-us`. If you don't know about mappings or paths, check [this tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/)